# Surface under the 'love formula'

Tags: integration

To plot the love formula, you can plot two functions in one diagram:

$$y_1(x)=\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt{1-x^2}+1$$
$$y_2(x)=\sqrt[3]{x^2}-\sqrt{1-x^2}+1$$

Then you get:
[Plot love function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7O7J2.jpg)

I calculated the surface inside the heart as, am I right of that:

$$2\int_{0}^{1}\left(\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt{1-x^2}+1\right)\space\text{d}x-2\int_{0}^{1}2\space\text{d}x+2\int_{0}^{1}2\space\text{d}x-2\int_{0}^{1}\left(\sqrt[3]{x^2}-\sqrt{1-x^2}+1\right)\space\text{d}x=\pi$$

Comment: Where do the second and third integral come from?

Comment: Area or Surface? Surfaces happen when working in 3D. :-)

Comment: I think that he meant area @Babaxor

Comment: Your last equations are not clear! Please give some comments on them! In my point of view $$A=\int_{-1}^{1}[y_1(x)-y_2(x)]dx$$

Comment: Tangible bingo globs flood the pavement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is correct but I have no idea where all those integrals come from. For me the area would be just one integral of the difference between the two functions, which yields the same formula as the area of the unit circle.